# Show hoverinfo in treemap only for child container in plotly treemap

Tags: plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I have created the treemap graph for share market summery, It shows correct information when i hover on child containers but when i hover on the parent container it shows different syntax, i want instead of that syntax some different values or stop hovering on the parent container at all

This is my written code.

```
Data_source = "data/dashbaord_ohlc_df_4_processed.csv"
PATH = ['Sector','Symbol']
HOVER_DATA = ['Name','Country','Currency','Market Capitalization', 'Most Recent Quarter','PE Ratio%','PEG Ratio%','Earnings Share','Dividend Yield','Operating Margin TTM','Return OnAssets TTM','Return OnEquity TTM','Quarterly Earnings GrowthYOY','Quarterly Revenue GrowthYOY','dailyChange']
value_attribute = 'Market Capitalization'
COLOR = 'dailyChange'
infotext =  "label + percent parent"
Hover_Tmp = '<br>Name:%{customdata[0]}'+'<br>Country:%{customdata[1]}'+'<br>Currency:%{customdata[2]}'+'<br>Daily Change: %{customdata[14]}%'+'<br>Market Capitalization:%{value:0.3s}'+'<br>Most Recent Quarter:%{customdata[4]}' +'<br>PE Ratio:%{customdata[5]}%'+'<br>PEG Ratio:%{customdata[6]}%'+'<br>Earnings Share:%{customdata[7]}%' +  '<br>Dividend Yield:%{customdata[8]}' + '<br>Operating Margin TTM:%{customdata[9]}' + '<br>Return OnAssets TTM:%{customdata[10]}' + '<br>Return OnEquity TTM:%{customdata[11]}' + '<br>Quarterly Earnings GrowthYOY:%{customdata[12]}' + '<br>Quarterly Revenue GrowthYOY:%{customdata[13]}'+'<br>'

df = pd.read_csv(Data_source, usecols = ['Name','Country','Currency','Market Capitalization', 'Most Recent Quarter','PE Ratio%','PEG Ratio%','Earnings Share','Dividend Yield','Operating Margin TTM','Return OnAssets TTM','Return OnEquity TTM','Quarterly Earnings GrowthYOY','Quarterly Revenue GrowthYOY', 'dailyChange', 'date', 'Sector', 'Symbol', 'DailyChangeTreeMap', 'Condition'])

df = pd.DataFrame(df) 

def update_output(theme_select, my_date_picker_single,dd_output_container):
    filter_df(my_date_picker_single,dd_output_container)
        indicator = px.treemap(filtered_df,
                    title = "Market Overview",
                    color=COLOR,
                    color_continuous_scale=color_discrete_map,
                    path = PATH, 
                    # template='plotly_white',
                    hover_data=HOVER_DATA, 
                    values=value_attribute,
                    color_discrete_map=color_discrete_map)

        indicator.update_traces(textfont_size=16,)
        indicator.update_layout(margin = dict(t=35, l=5, r=5, b=5),
                        paper_bgcolor='rgba(0,0,255,0)',
                        plot_bgcolor='rgba(0,0,255,0)',
                        # coloraxis_showscale=False
                        )
        indicator.data[0].hovertemplate = Hover_Tmp
            indicator.data[0].texttemplate ="<b>%{label} </b><br><span class='innertext'>% customdata[14]} %<br>Market Cap.:%{value:0.3s}"

    
        return indicator
```

This is parent container image, which i don't want to display on the hover

[image]

this is second parent image i dont want that much of details on that hover else don't show anything on the hover

[image]

This is container hover image, I only want this hover effect on the child container

[image]

I only want to show detailed hover info on the child element & stop hover on the parent container

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide your data, so you may have to make some changes to make this work.

I've created two examples since I can't see the structure of your treemap, one uses `px.constant` and one does not. I can see that you have *not* used this function. If you use `px.constant`, it will address a lot of the issues with your hover content.

Here's the first example data and treemap. This uses `px.constant`, in the call to `px.treemap`, you can see that it's the variable named `world`.

```
import plotly.express as px
import numpy as np
import plotly.io as pio

# example data frame, treemap, & layout from Plotly docs
df = px.data.gapminder().query("year == 2007")

fig = px.treemap(df, path = [px.Constant("world"), 'continent', 'country'], 
                 values = 'pop', color = 'lifeExp', hover_data = ['iso_alpha'],
                 color_continuous_scale = 'RdBu', 
                 color_continuous_midpoint = np.average(df['lifeExp'], 
                                                        weights = df['pop']))
fig.update_layout(margin = dict(t = 50, r = 25, b = 25, l = 25))
```

Now when I render this, I'm going to use `pio.show(fig, ...`, not `fig.show`. If you need to write this to a file, these arguments will work in `pio.write_html`, as well. The argument `post_script` allows you to add Javascript to your rendering.

Considerations When Using `px.constant`:

> If you *use* `px.constant` and still want to remove the hover content from the first two levels (because treemaps can be many layers of parents and children), the name assigned in that function will need to be swapped out for the word `world` in the JS.

> In approximately the middle of these lines of Javascript code there is a line that has `if(pth === '/' || pth === 'world/')`. If you use `px.constant`, you have to change `world` for whatever you have named or assigned your root container.

If you don't use `px.constant`, leave this exactly as it is. (The 'path' in the Plotly object after rendering for the first two levels is `"/"` with no constant.)

```
pio.show(fig,
         post_script = "/* this works if there is only one Plotly plot on web page */" +
         "setTimeout(function() {" +
         "  el = document.querySelector('div.plotly-graph-div.js-plotly-plot'); " +
         "  /* Plotly event */" +
         "  el.on('plotly_hover', function(d){" +
         "    pth = d.points[0].currentPath;"     +
         "    if(pth === '/' || pth === 'world/') {    /* if root or first root child (a parent) */" +
         "       ght = document.querySelector('g.hoverlayer');"
         "       ght.innerHTML = ''; /* remove hovertext */" +
         "    }" +
         "  });" +
         "}, 200)")
```

Here's that treemap example again, but with `px.constant` removed, using the same Javascript code.

```
fig1 = px.treemap(df, path=['continent', 'country'], values='pop',
                  color='lifeExp', hover_data=['iso_alpha'],
                  color_continuous_scale='RdBu',
                  color_continuous_midpoint=np.average(df['lifeExp'], weights=df['pop']))
pio.show(fig1,
         post_script = "/* this works if there is only one Plotly plot on web page */" +
         "setTimeout(function() {" +
         "  el = document.querySelector('div.plotly-graph-div.js-plotly-plot'); " +
         "  /* Plotly event */" +
         "  el.on('plotly_hover', function(d){" +
         "    pth = d.points[0].currentPath;"     +
         "    if(pth === '/' || pth === 'world/') {    /* if root or first root child (a parent) */" +
         "       ght = document.querySelector('g.hoverlayer');"
         "       ght.innerHTML = ''; /* remove hovertext */" +
         "    }" +
         "  });" +
         "}, 200)")
```

This first 2 images has the root named `world`. There is no hover label when you hover on the `world` or a continent. However, there are labels when you hover on a country.

[image]--------[image]

The remaining images have a blank root (black) container. There are no labels when you hover on that black frame or on a continent. In this first image, I'm hovering on Europe (it's a bit difficult to tell).

[image]--------[image]

One last thing. Here is the Javascript without all the " and +:

```js
setTimeout(function() {
 /* this works if there is only one Plotly plot in the webpage */
el = document.querySelector('div.plotly-graph-div.js-plotly-plot'); 

/* Plotly event */
el.on('plotly_hover', function(d){
    pth = d.points[0].currentPath;
                        /* if root or first root child (a parent) */
    if(pth === "/" || pth === "world/") {
        ght = document.querySelector('g.hoverlayer');
        ght.innerHTML = "";
    } 
});
}, 200)
```

Comment: Atually i am rendering the Figure in HTML Code, so how can i render it to html, cause its using the fig.show()

Comment: `pio.show(fig)` does the same thing as `fig.show`. However, `pio.show` has the added argument `post_script` which you need for this. It still renders in HTML, just like `fig.show`. As a user, you won't be able to tell a difference.

Comment: Hi Kat, Thank You so much for responces. Actually my problem is still not solved, that's why i am asking new qestion with great clarity of question. please help with this question, please check out this question in my account.

Comment: I looked at your new question. It is the same question. You want tooltips for the 3rd level, not for the root or middle level. That's what this answer does. What is the difference between what this answer does and what you're looking for?